# pkg.fcn instead of pkg.a.b.c.d.fcn

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

If I use a PyPI package `pkg` which contains a function `fcn` that can be imported like that:

```py
from pkg.a.b.c.d import fcn

fcn
```

Is there a way to import `fcn` so I can refer to it like the following?

```py
pkg.fcn
```

I must specify that I don't control the source code of the package `pkg`. So I can't edit its `__init__.py` files or change the directory structure.

Comment: `import pkg.a.b.c.d as pkg` but that forbids to use the real `pkg` base after, So I'd suggest using another name like `import pkg.a.b.c.d as pkgfull`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.